# Manually remove git conflict markers using PHP regex

Tags: php, regex, git

I would like to remove the Git conflict markers using PHP Regex.

I need help with the regular expression to search for the text with '<<<<<<< Updated upstream' and '======='. I would then remove the markers including the string between them from the file.

I also need to remove the '>>>>>>> Stashed changes' string.

example:

```
<<<<<<< Updated upstream
    'first_name','middle_name','last_name','username', 'email', 'password'
=======
    'branch_id', 'first_name','middle_name','last_name','username', 'email', 'password'
>>>>>>> Stashed changes
```

desired output:

```
'branch_id', 'first_name','middle_name','last_name','username', 'email', 'password'
```

my current code:

```
$base_dir    = '/xampp/htdocs/sample/';

function get_files($path)
{
    $files = array_filter(glob($path.'/*'), 'is_file');
    return $files;
}

$iter = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
            new RecursiveDirectoryIterator(
                $base_dir, RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS
            ),
            RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST,
            RecursiveIteratorIterator::CATCH_GET_CHILD
        );

$paths = array($base_dir);
foreach ($iter as $path => $dir) {
    if ($dir->isDir()) {
        if (strpos($path, '.git') === false) {
            $files = get_files($path);
            if (count($files) !== 0)
            {
                foreach($files as $file)
                {
                    $content = file_get_contents($file);
                    $matches = array();
                    $start = '<<<<<<< Updated upstream';
                    $end = '=======';
                    $regex = "/$start([a-zA-Z0-9_]*)$end/";
                    preg_match_all($regex, $content, $matches);
                    var_dump($regex);exit();
                }
            }
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: Your question has a fundamental problem: When resolving a conflicted file in Git, the resolution process involves _also_ removing a certain parent's version of code in _addition_ to removing all markers.  Do you intend your PHP code to be smart enough to know how to resolve a merge conflict?

Comment: I'm using the code as is without a parent. I just need to strip the conflict markers and just preserve the latest edits and remove the old code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the requirements given, I guess you always need to replace the

```
<<<<<<< Updated upstream
<some lines>
=======
<some other lines>
>>>>>>> Stashed changes
```

with

```
<some other lines>
```

The following would be the one you are looking for:

```
preg_replace("/<<<<<<< Updated upstream(?:.|\s)+=======((?:.|\s)+)>>>>>>> Stashed changes/", "$1", $input_lines);
```

where `$input_lines` contains the text with conflict.

Here we are capturing the text between `=======` and `>>>>>>> Stashed changes` to replace the entire text starting with `<<<<<<< Updated upstream` and ending with `>>>>>>> Stashed changes`.

**EDIT**: As Wiktor suggested, this can be refined by utilizing DOTALL modifier as in

```
preg_replace("/<<<<<<< Updated upstream.+?=======(.+?)>>>>>>> Stashed changes/s", "$1", $input_lines);
```

Comment: All cases of `(?:.|\s)+` should be replaced with `.*?` and the `s` DOTALL modifier should be added after the last regex delimiter.